# Access to the path 'GoogleAnalytics.Auth.Store' is denied

Tags: c#-4.0, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I created a WebForm project that Getting data from Google API.
for getting the data, I should make authentication with Oauth2 which working great while I runing my project from iis express via visual studio 2013

```
    internal static UserCredential GetCredential()
    {
        string[] scopes = { AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly };

        return GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                                                          new ClientSecrets { ClientId = ClientId, ClientSecret = ClientSecret },
                                                          scopes,
                                                          Environment.UserName,
                                                          CancellationToken.None,
                                                          new FileDataStore(@"GoogleAnalytics.Auth.Store")).Result;
    }
```

Somehow, while I running the project via external host (meaning local iis), i get the following exception:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'GoogleAnalytics.Auth.Store' is denied.

giving premissions to appdata folder or to project folder didn't help.

Any answer will be evaluated

Comment: try FileDataStore(".",true)

Comment: As specified here, you have to use the full path and set the fullPath argument as true, https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.9.1/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Util_1_1Store_1_1FileDataStore the path can be obtained from the hosting environment